# Sql cursor loop taking a minute to loop through 20 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, loops, cursor

The code from the loop below is taking up to a minute to complete. I've removed all processing /calculations in the body of the loop to try and pinpoint what is taking so long and so it appears just iterating over the rows (only 20) is what is taking time. Would re-writing it as a while loop increase performance or is there something inherently wrong with the code below?

```
declare tl_cursor cursor local forward_only dynamic optimistic
for 
select EId, Date, Hrs, Code1, Code2,  TLId, Acc
from TLines where Account < 0 and Date=@magicdate
for update of Cost, Charge, Acc, RowId, ParentTLId

open tl_cursor
fetch next from tl_cursor
into @tl_eid, @tl_date, @tl_hrs, @tl_account, @tl_tlid

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
   --Removed all calculations in there to narrow down bottleneck
NextRecord:
    update TLines set Acc = 0 where current of tl_cursor

    fetch next from tl_cursor
    into @tl_eid, @tl_date, @tl_hrs, @tl_account, @tl_timelineid
end

close tl_cursor
deallocate tl_cursor
```

Comment: Any time I see a cursor in SQL, I think there has to be a better way.  Are you sure there's not a set-based approach to do what you want?

Comment: Yes, it is the cursor's fault the code runs slow. A WHILE loop should increase the performance of the query. A cursor does iterate over every row, but then again, a WHILE loop would do the same (albeit with less overhead)

Comment: How big is your TLines table? If it is huge and there is no index on the Account column, that maybe is a source of problem?

Comment: @Ricardo: The number of rows is mentioned in the question.

Comment: Rule #1 about cursors in SQL Server: ***AVOID THEM!***

Comment: @Twinkles I don't mean the rows returned by the cursor, I mean the total number of rows in the table since he/she is filtering all `Account < 0`.

Comment: @Ricardo's statement is interesting. Can you try doing a select for the same set of records and seeing the timing on that? Agree on the comments of cursor overhead, but maybe a significant part of the time is spent just getting the records.

Comment: I bet the minute is spent waiting to acquire the locks for your cursor. Are there other transactions running at the same time?

Comment: Yeah its very bing > 1 million rows. Did as you said and its cut it down to a second. There are 7 other indexes on the table and thought it was covered. Thanks

Comment: I should clarify the number of rows in the select at the beginning is ~20 rows but the TLines table itself has > 1million

Answer (score 7):

Isn't that identical to:

```
UPDATE TLines 
SET Acc = 0
WHERE Account < 0 AND Date=@magicdate
```

Comment: Not quite. While this would work for the final statement as I've posted here I need to use the current row (where current of tl_cursor) in the body of the loop which i've commented out

Comment: Yes, but are you sure these calculations could not also be expressed as a query?

Comment: Yes fair point, I think they can in some way. I didn't know using the cursor was so degrading so i have to try replace them with queries. The index seems to have bee the main problem though. You probably hadn't accounted for such an oversight which i don't blame you

Answer (score 3):

This would probably be faster:

```
UPDATE  TLines
SET     Acc = 0
WHERE   Account < 0 
  and   Date=@magicdate
```

If you want to read more about why and how to avoid Cursors in T-Sql, check out this article: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66097/.  Sadly, the notoriously opinionated author never finished the series, but the first two articles should help get you started.

Comment: Not quite. While this would work for the final statement as I've posted here I need to use the current row (where current of tl_cursor) in the body of the loop which i've commented out

Comment: Thanks for the article also

Comment: @user48408 We can only answer the questions that you ask and help you with the things that you actually show us.  If you want to see how to incorporate the body of the loop into a set-based solution, show them to us.